# How to get information from generic node in Linked List that is a class

Tags: java, linked-list, queue

I'm working on a question that asks us to add customers in a queue based off of the amount of time it will take to help a customer. The customers that take the least amount of time are the ones that will be helped first (doesn't really make sense but oh well).

I've already created a generic "public class MyQueue" and the main idea of the problem is to just inherit the MyQueue into our ServiceQueue class and essentially just over right our push method. This isn't the complete code and I know it doesn't work:

```
void push(CustomerRequest request){
       if (head == null)
   {
        Node newHead = new Node(request);
        head = newHead;
   }
       else {

        Node newCustomer = new Node(request);
        Node node = head;
        int count;

        while(request.requiredServiceTime > node-->*(I need the service time)*)
        {
            node = node.next;
        }
        ///insert node here
       }
    }
```

There is also the CustomerRequest class:

```
public class CustomerRequest {

String name;
int requiredServiceTime;

public CustomerRequest(String name, int requiredServiceTime){
    this.name = name;
    this.requiredServiceTime = requiredServiceTime;

}
}
```

My question is: How do I get the requiredServiceTime information out of the node that I created and that needs to be put into the Queue?

ADDED:

```
public class Node<T> {

    Node<T> next;
T data;

public Node(T data)
{
    this.data = data;
}

public Node(T data, Node<T> next)
{
    this.data = data;
    this.next = next;
}
```

}

Comment: Please show us your Node class.

Comment: Just added the Node Class

Answer (score 0):

Why does it have to be a linked list?
I would put the CustomerRequests into a SortedSet and pass a custom Comparator (that compares the requiredeServiceTimes) to the constructor of the SortedSet. 
The details are documented here:
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/SortedSet.html

Once the elements are in the SortedSet, you can get the quickest customers from the front of the set with "first()".

Comment: I'm in a data structures class so we have to create all the data structures. We can't use any imports.

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered using a `PriorityQueue`, instead of your own queue implementation?  Priority queues are a very efficient means of picking minimum values.  These have been a part of the standard JRE for a *very* long time. See [the PriorityQueue javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/PriorityQueue.html).

The trick is to then update your classes so their default sorting is the order you want.  You can also define a `Comparator` for your queue that sorts the `CustomerRequest` in the order you want.

I'd use a `PriorityQueue` for your queue, and then update `CustomerRequest` so that it implements `Comparable<CustomerRequest>` in such a way that the natural ordering sorts by the required service time. Below is a pretty naive implementation:

```
public class CustomerRequest implements Comparable<CustomerRequest> {
    // existing code
    ...
    // Implement Comparable
    public int compareTo(CustomerRequest obj) {
        // Sort by required service time ascending
        if (this.requiredServiceTime > obj.requiredServiceTime)
            return 1;
        else if (this.requiredServiceTime < obj.requiredServiceTime)
            return -1;
        else
            // Sort by name to break ties
            return this.name.compareTo(obj.name);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Declare an interface like Comparable (http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Comparable.html). You don't have to import it if you are not allowed to, just make it yourself:

```
public interface Comparable<T> {
     int compareTo(T other);
}
```

Let your CustomerRequest implement Comparable:

```
public class CustomerRequest implements Comparable {
    ...
```

Let your LinkedList require data that implements Comparable:

```
public class Node<T extends Comparable> {
    ...
```

Then you can use compareTo in your insertion sort.